# Outlook not displaying .msg files correctly

Tags: outlook

I have stored .msg files in a Sharepoint document library. This library is connected to Outlook. When I try to preview any of the .msg files in  Outlook, they are not displayed like regular messages. You can see it on the right side in the image.

Is there a way to make these files display correctly in Outlook? Maybe Outlook is using some sort of templates for displaying different file types, which I can edit or create?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you get a document item with an MSG file as an attachment.

This is exactly what you would get if you store MSG files. Do you mean you want this to look like a regular message? I don't think you can do that. Documents are not messages.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, yes I want it displayed as regular message. Do you know in what format should I store it so I can display it as a regular message?

Comment: What should I store them as?

Comment: That is my whole point - SharePoint only stores documents (files), and to see it as a regular message, it must be a regular message.  Which to the best of my knowledge SharePoint Server store provider does not do.